# Absolute cell references not working as I'd expect, what am I doing wrong

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am working on a sheet that tracks yearly budgets to review/see trends in the data. I am trying to make it user friendly and essentially "dummy-proof" for lack of a better word.

Most of the data is being imported from a different document for each year and I am asking the user to paste the link to that document in a different tab of this sheet. So my import function looks like this:

`=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`

My problem is, the D19 reference is not changing as I need it to when I copy/paste or drag the formula. In the main data display tab I have each year in columns. For example, in `Summary!F13` I have the following formula:

`=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`

When I copy/paste or drag it into `Summary!G13` I get the exact same thing:
`=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`

but I need this instead:
`=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D20,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`

I can drag the formula down the column and the cell reference changes on each row like you'd expect - if I bring it to `Summary!F14` I get `=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D20,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`. But I need this result in `Summary!G13`, not `Summary!F14`.

My question is, how do I make it so D19 to changes to D20, D21, etc. when I drag it to an adjacent column in the same row?

Comment: Lots of words but hard to follow.  [edit] your question to include a few simple examples of the result you are getting and what you want.  eg. I have `=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!$P$15")` in cell `Sheet!xA1` I paste it in to  `Sheet!yA1` and I get `=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!$P$15")` but I want `=IMPORTRANGE(dontsetup!$F72,"Monthly Summary!$P$15")`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are you importing the data _one cell_ at a time? The `importrange()` function is usually applied with a larger range reference to bring in _all_ the necessary data in one go, often in a separate `'Import'` tab, so that the data is easy to reference elsewhere in the target spreadsheet.

Comment: Also sounds like you are transposing data from column to a row.  Might be best to make a question with the main use case [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) as you are MacGuyvering stuff that may not need to be.

Comment: @cotimms If you are still using multiple IMPORTRANGE formulas you are probably still using way too many.  Also if you are dragging the formula down you may wish to look at other options to have one formula populate all the rows as needed.

Comment: @Blindspots thanks for the info. Tried clarifying things a bit in my OP. At minimum I need a new IMPORTRANGE function for each yearly sheet being imported by the user - after doubleunary's suggestion it is now just 1 import function for each year being tracked.

Comment: np.  FYI **`"Annual Summary!$P$14:$P$57"`**  is equivalent to **`"Annual Summary!P14:P57"`**  because they are strings so will never update (wrapped in quotations **`"`**)  If you *needed* that string to update you would need to build it dynamically as you are doing for the URLs.

Comment: understood - I learned about absolute references quite recently while trying to find a solution to my problem on this website lol, and added it to every reference except the one I need to be changed when pasting. Good to know I don't need absolutes for a string

Answer (score 1):

> `=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`
>
> When I copy/paste or drag it into Summary!G13 I get the exact same thing: `=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D19,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`
>
> but I need this instead: `=IMPORTRANGE(Setup!$D20,"Annual Summary!P14:P57")`

You currently have sheet IDs in the **column** `Setup!D19:D22`.

To make those references work the way you want, place the sheet IDs in the **row** `Setup!D19:G19`.

You should also remove the remaining `$` in the `importrange()` formula.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that to have a better UX - previously I did have the sheet IDs in the same row on the main summary tab, but felt they were better suited in the setup tab; the way I have the setup tab formatted/laid out it makes more sense for them to be in the same column. With your earlier advice to cut down on the amount of import functions I may just do it manually or look for better ways to format the sheet so having the references in the same row doesn't seem out of place. Thanks!